# 4 x 4 Board Design in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I just need a little bit help in windows form. I'm just want to design a 4 x 4 board in windows form as shown below.
Thanks[image]

Comment: This requires you design a control that looks like a single block.  I would then place 8 of them on a single form.

Comment: Also, the picture you posted is 3x3, not 4x4.

Comment: @Ramhound - 8 as in 2x4 or did you think about 3x3 with a hole in the middle?

Comment: Posted picture not mean it is same as i said. It just a view. Let it be n X n

Answer (score 1):

Use a TableLayoutPanel, you can read up on it here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx